# How to deploy desktop icons for win form project?

Tags: c#, winforms

We have multiple set of configurations (Dev/ UAT/ Production) in our windows form project.

We are using [slow-cheetah](https://github.com/microsoft/slow-cheetah) extension for configuration file transformation.

We want separate desktop icon for each release. For that I have added below property in csproje file

```
<applicationIcon>icon.ico</applicationIcon>
```

To display different icons for different configuration, I have added following property in separate property group

Example
For UAT

```
<PropertyGroup Condition = "'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='UAT|AnyCPU">
   <applicationIcon>UATIcon.ico</applicationIcon>
</PropertyGroup>
```

For production

```
<PropertyGroup Condition = "'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='PRD|AnyCPU">
     <applicationIcon>PRDIcon.ico</applicationIcon>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

It is working fine. Each release is displaying different icons on desktop.

But when I release solution, it adds both icons in installation folder in user's machine.
UAT's installation folder have both UAT and PRD icon get deployed and same for production release.

How can I restrict production icon to deploy while release for UAT and vice versa?

---

Edit :
I tried to use `<ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>` in my winform project as mentioned by ExplodatedFaces, but it is not working. Any additional steps need to do to exclude files for particular configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding `ExcludeFilesFromDeployment` to avoid building each version with multiple ico files.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition = "'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='UAT|AnyCPU">
    <applicationIcon>UATIcon.ico</applicationIcon>
    <ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
        DEVIcon.ico;PRDIcon.ico
    </ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer , but it is not working, need to do any additional steps with this?
My project is Win form project

Comment: You may need to use the Rebuild feature instead of Build. When you Build a solution Visual Studio will only update files that have changed. Try using Rebuild which will completely remove the entire compiled project and rebuild the solution from scratch.

Comment: we are using msbuild to build our project, I tried with it and it does not working,